# Hugo: put {{ .Content }} to same line as some link before

Tags: hugo

I want to do this:

```
<a href="">[i]</a>{{ .Content }}
```

The content should be displayed at the same line, not in a new line. (Playnify isn't good, because it will remove any newline within `.Content` as well and I want to keep these.)
Any ideas?

Comment: What output do you want? Can you give an example? Also you need to show what the front matter looks like, because that will also determine what the content will look like. Show an example of the layout template also.

Comment: A new line in your HTML file does not cause a newline in the rendered output. This may be some general misunderstanding about HTML. If there is a break, it probably because your content does not fit next to your link and you need to fix the HTML itself, completely independent from Hugo.